# What is the name of this 90's Planechase-like Magic format?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, identify-this-game

I have a vague memory of an unofficial Magic format from the 90's, that was similar in some ways to Planechase or Vanguard. In addition to the players' regular decks, there were cards that applied rules changes from "outside the game" ("command zone" by modern terminology), like Vanguards or Planes. A lot of the "command" cards were based on World Enchantments; some may have been based on other enchantments or artifacts with static abilities. I don't remember if each player picked one like Vanguard, or there was rotation like Planechase.

There was a site that listed the rules and had images of the "command" cards for making proxies. I saw it around 2001-2003, and it seemed a little old then.

Does anyone know what this format was called, or any extant sites with information about it?

Comment: I was pretty active in Magic in 97 and don't recall this, so I think it's from after that. Either 98, 99, or the early 2000s. Although it's possible it had been developed and just had very little popularity in my circles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds a lot like the [Chaos](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Chaos_Magic) format.

> Chaos is a casual multiplayer format for Magic: the Gathering where the players add a Chaos Deck to the game to create new and exciting challenges. Chaos Magic is a variant of Free-for-All and might be considered an early form of Planechase.
>
> The Chaos deck consists of 20–30 cards selected by some of the players involved. The player who goes first is designated the Chaos player; before that player untaps at the beginning of their turn, that player flips a card from the Chaos Deck face up on the table. That card is considered "in effect" until the Chaos player flips a different card after a full series of turns. The active Chaos card isn't in play and can't be affected by spells or abilities. Any player may use any abilities granted by the card, or, if it has a specific effect, each player immediately resolves the effect.

The earliest reference I can find to this is [the "Mixing It Up" article on wizards.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20090122153346/http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx%3Fx=mtgcom/daily/tf64) (archive link), posted 11 December, 2007, which describes a few formats including Chaos Magic.

Comment: Fantastic lead!

Comment: Chaos also got a lot of exposure since it was built into "Apprentice," a client popular in the late 90s and early 00s for playing magic online.

Comment: @Chuu I haven't been able to find any reference saying [Apprentice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_(software)) supported Chaos by design. Although Apprentice lacked a rules engine, didn't have the concept of card ownership and allowed creating cards on the spot. That seems to provide the flexibility to play something resembling Chaos if players are already familiar with that.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Apprentice by default had a menu option to roll a chaos die, and I believe also had an option to add a "chaos phase" to the phases of a turn to allow for chaos.  It did have an option to draw from one of the chaos decks as well, but I do not remember how it worked.  If you look in Addon.dat in Apprentice 1.4 you can see all the chaos rolls, for example, "Chaos1="Eureka" - All Players can drop Permanents into play, one at a time, until no player wishes to play more."  Online chaos tournaments were run, including once where the winner would add a card to PersonaLand.

Comment: If anyone is curious, Addon.dat from Apprentice v1.4: https://pastebin.com/HYNSZmsm  The ChaosMagic/WackyLand/PersonaLand/EnchantWorldLand are all part of the "chaos" ruleset.  EnchantWorldLand and PersonaLand do resemble planechase planes.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be referring to the "World Enchantment" format, also known as "Worlds". In this format, players would bring their own decks, but in addition to those decks, there would be a shared pool of "world enchantments" that would affect the game. The enchantments would be placed face-down on the table, and each turn, the active player would reveal the top card and apply its rules for that turn. Some versions of the format had players vote on which enchantment to use. I did some research with Google but wasn't able to find any website mentioning the format, but I am pretty positive to have read about it in a magazine in the late 90's.

Comment: There is a [world](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/World) enchantment type, but I can't find any link whatsoever to a format featuring these. It might be an obscure custom format (the 90s was very much the era of someone writing a random idea they had in a magazine, a bunch of people following that, no-one else having ever heard about it, and there being no traceable historic reference of it).